# Javafx Tree Table view: how to assign serial number to the direct child nodes of the root node

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to number the direct child nodes of the root node in a serial manner (child-1, child-2...).
Here is my method which sets the cell value factory for myColumn:

```
private void setCellValueFactory() {
    myColumn.setPrefWidth(120);
    final int[] si_SubsetCount = {
        1
    };
    myColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures < MyDataClass, String > p) - > {
        TreeItem < JVCC_PageHeaderInfo > ti_Row = p.getValue();
        MyDataClass myDataClass = p.getValue().getValue();
        String text;
        if (ti_Row.isLeaf()) {
            //leaf
        } else if (ti_Row.getParent() != null) {
            text = "Child-" + si_SubsetCount[0];
            si_SubsetCount[0]++;
        } else {
            si_SubsetCount[0] = 1;
            text = "Root";
        }
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper < > (text);
    });
 }
```

But my output is as below:

```
>Root
  >child-4
    >leaf
    >leaf
  >child-8
    >leaf
    >leaf
```

I don't understand why the numbering is like 4, 8... instead of 1, 2...

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you can not control, when the CellValueFactorys method for evaluating the value for each row is called. It might get called several times for a single row, which is why your counter does not show the correct value for each line.

A dynamical approach is prefered here. If you should only have to differ between 3 node levels like root/child/leaf, then you could do something like this:

```
myColumn.setCellValueFactory( ( final CellDataFeatures<String, String> p ) ->
{
  final TreeItem<String> value = p.getValue();
  String text = "";

  if ( value.isLeaf() )
    text = "leaf";
  else if ( value.getParent() != null )
    text = "Child-" + (value.getParent().getChildren().indexOf( value ) + 1);
  else
    text = "root";

  return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper( text );
} );
```

Since the Children of a TreeItem are stored in an ObservableList, you can just ask them for their index and add 1, since index starts at zero.

Comment: Just for my info, Is there any logic behind the CellValueFactory getting called multiple times?

Comment: I am not too familiar with the Implementation myself. I just noticed this, when I experimented with creating new rows and changing visible states (expanding/collapsing). In general I am a bit coutious with methods taking care of rendering a value to be displayed on the screen, which probably comes from my java swing background. In javafx the mechanism is different, but still I try to minimize overhead in those methods. So there maybe are even far better implementations for your usecase then mine. This was just the first thing, which came up in my mind.